# Acquiring the first column of a CSV file without reading entire rows in C++

Tags: c++, csv

Let's assume that we have a header-less CSV file (I'm including a header row for clarification but the actual file doesn't contain it):

```
ID,BookTitle,Author,Price
110,book1,author1,price1
178,book2,author2,price2
917,book3,author3,price3
```

How can I acquire the ID column without having to read whole rows of data into memory? i.e. read ID: `110` and add to a vector, go to next row (line), read ID: `178` and add to vector, and so on.

Comment: do all lines have the same width? Or is this just conincidence in your example?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 By width, do you mean the same number of columns or just characters? We always have 4 columns but the id, title, author or price might have different values and lengths.

Comment: I mean number of characters

Comment: Do you control the CSV creation? If so, you could add an additional column "RowLength" containing the row length in bytes as the first column and use that data to calculate how many bytes to skip until the next line.
This would lead to a lot of troubles, though. Just think of character encodings where characters and bytes aren't the same for example.

Comment: @z80crew Wow, a really nice and creative solution. You're right, it's kind of a dirty solution but an actual working one.

Comment: @FadeLights Perhaps you could elaborate why you want to avoid reading the whole row.

Comment: @z80crew I was just thinking of ways to optimize the performance in case a CSV contains large row data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future readers who might stumble upon this question:

@largest_prime 's answer is the reasonable one. If your row data isn't that large (which for 99.99% of times, this is the case), it makes perfect sense to read it all, acquire the `ID` data and finally discard the rest of the row data.

However, in that 0.01% of the times that a row might contain big data (such as a whole book's text), @z80crew 's solution might work out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Files don't have rows and columns. The content is just characters and a `\n` denotes a line break. Hence, you cannot know where a line starts or ends without reading characters until you find a line break.

Situation is different when lines have a fixed width. Then you can skip ahead and start reading the next line.